# Ajax large-ish file upload with FormData and jQuery fails to post the data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, form-data

I am trying to upload files via AJAX using FormData. If I submit the AJAX call without selecting any files to upload, the post works fine, and other fields (that are not file uploads) are received on the server OK. If I select a file to upload though, the call arrives at the server with no data whatsoever (in PHP, the $_POST and $_FILES arrays are both completely empty). I understand this can happen if you fail to tell jQuery not to set the contentType, but I am setting contentType and processData to false and it still won't send the data.

Here is my code:

```
function AddComment(taskid) {
    var newnote = $('#newnote_'+taskid).val();
    if(newnote != '') {
        $('#tasklist *').css('cursor', 'progress');
        var formData = new FormData();

        $('.upload-' + taskid).each(function() {
            if (this.files[0]) {
                formData.append($(this).attr('name'), this.files[0]);
            }
        });
        formData.append("taskid", taskid);
        formData.append("newnote", newnote);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/modules/task/ajax/ajaxAddComment.php',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I can't see what...?

Edit: Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="frmNewComment544" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<div>
    <textarea style="width:100%;" cols="30" rows="5" id="newnote_544"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" onclick="AddComment(544)" value="Append Comment">    
</div>
<div class="attachment-browsers" id="attachmentBrowsers544" style="display: block;">Attachments will be uploaded when you append a comment.
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="upload_544_151ab3cfe69" name="upload_544_151ab3cfe69" class="upload-544">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="upload_544_3y4afe6eg7a" name="upload_544_3y4afe6eg7a" class="upload-544">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Edit 2: OK, the problem only occurs when uploading relatively large files (not massive - in this case it was 10MB). Small files upload OK. So now the question is why I cannot upload large files using this method?

Comment: Can you post the `html` form too?

Comment: please check all the parameters with console.log() and check any of getting failed can break post data send failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew it would be something stupid!

My php.ini had the default 2MB limit for file uploads. D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reference to your form.
May be you would do it like this:

```
.....

      var form = $('form#frmNewComment544');

        var formdata = false;

        if (window.FormData){
            formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
        }

        var formAction = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            url: formAction,
            data : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),

....
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried passing the form in the constructor instead of appending the data, but the results were the same.

Comment: I jut saw that you have update your question. So this is now something else the your original one.

Comment: I did edit my question to post the form HTML, however, the code is working for small files, just not for larger files (10MB). So I don't think there is anything wrong with the code as such, I am just hitting some kind of limit (but I don't know what).

Comment: I think you know better than me about 'max_file_size ' in 'php.ini'. I see also that you are uploading multiple files. Can you upload all the files when they are of a small size?

Comment: If you are running PHP as an apache module, you will need to restart apache before changes to php.ini take effect. Also make sure file_uploads is on, and that your post_max_size is at least the same as upload_max_filesize

Comment: Thanks, but I actually just got it. In my case, the problem was in php.ini. I had a typo somewhere in it so it didn't load the proper php.ini and the `max_file_size` was indeed just 2MB.